# how to do validation for username in [objective-c]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, uitextfield

my requirement for `validation` is to validate `username` which allows to enter small a-z,and 0-9, and only two symbol `_` and `.`(dot)

but symbol do not repeat.

and symbol not allowed at the starting of the name.

can any one help me ?? how to do this `validation`?

i have tried this code but it works fine but it repeats symbol how can i avoid to repeat?

```
- (BOOL)validateString:(NSString*)stringToSearch
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[a-z0-9._]{5,15}";
    NSPredicate *regex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [regex evaluateWithObject:stringToSearch];



}
```

Comment: please include a couple of sample inputs that should be rejected or approved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following regex to check if the characters are correct:

```
^([a-z0-9]+[._])*[a-z0-9]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7vX0VZXU7rPQLtE3)

Additionally and separately check the string length. (or use lookaheads)

*Edit:* it seems like I misread some of the requirements. The above regex disallows symbol at the end of the name as well. If you want to allow symbols there, change the regex to
`^([a-z0-9]+[._]?)*$`

*If you use predicates you can omit the leading `^` and trailing `$`.*

Comment: Good explanation. This might be what @prince actually wants. But the requirement doesn't cover "last not symbol"

Comment: @zcui93 yes, I realized that a second ago as well.

Comment: @zcui93 : how can i avoid to enter character which is rejected by  regex ^([a-z0-9]+[._])*[a-z0-9]+$ condition??

Comment: Edit feature makes my answer seem to be useless. What a shame.

Comment: @prince that is different topic, please ask that one as a new and separate question on SO.

Comment: please help me for email@luk2302

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247893/how-to-do-validation-for-email-in-objective-c my question @luk2302

Comment: You suggested amazing website.

Answer (score 1):

Pure regex approach, used lookahead for count, might have other simplified solution

```
"(?=[a-z0-9._]{5,15})([a-z0-9][._]?)+"
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the additional question: What to avoid the user enter rejected characters

Technically you can achieve that by implementing the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textView(_:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)`. But it might give the user impression that the keyboard is not responding correctly.

So it might be a better user experience that implementing `textViewShouldEndEditing(_:)` method with some kind of alert showing the alert.

Answer (score 1):

## define Validation   @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     NSCharacterSet *unacceptedInput = nil;
     unacceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ALPHA] invertedSet];
            
            if ([[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unacceptedInput] count] <= 1) {
                
                int newLength = (int)textField.text.length + (int)string.length - (int)range.length;
                if (newLength > 50) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
}
```

here I had to also put validation for text length not exceed 50 characters in my project so you can remove that condition